# Display Scheduled Jobs of SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have a Spring Boot application running inside a docker container. There are few scheduled jobs configured in the application. Is it possible to display all the running jobs of the application using some commands?
Consider the following sample code.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* */10 * * * ?")
public void scheduleTaskWithCronExpression() {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(300);
    logger.info("Cron Task :: Execution Time - {}", dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
}
```

The above code runs every 10 minutes. The duration of the job is 5 minutes(It just sleeps for 5 min). I want to know if there is any command such that when run between 9:10 and 9:15, it should output anything related to the job(Process Id,Started at,Status,ThreadGroup etc), when run between 9:15 and 9:20 , the output should be blank.

Comment: Depends. How did you schedule them?

Comment: Using @Scheduled annotation

Comment: fixedRate? fixedDelay? cron?

Comment: Cron Expressions like (* 12 * * *)

Comment: Can you add an example of what exactly would you like to "display" about the job? Its status? Some custom information? In general You could create an actuator endpoint and access this data via WEB / JMX...

Comment: Consider the following sample code.
@Scheduled(cron = "* */10 * * * ?")
    public void scheduleTaskWithCronExpression() {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(300);
        logger.info("Cron Task :: Execution Time - {}", dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
    }
The above code runs every 10 minutes. The duration of the job is 5 minutes(It just sleeps for 5 min). I want to know if there is any command such that when run between 9:10 and 9:15, it should output anything related to the job(Process Id, ThreadGroup etc), when run between 9:15 and 9:20 , the output should be blank.